# How to correct a problem with the transition of the shared element transition Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-element-transition

I'm doing an animation with shared element transition, when I move to the next activity I program an onClick to a button to hide a view, the problem is the following: 
When I minimize the application and then I re-maximize the app the view I hide reappears as visible

Verify that when I call the startActivity without the bundle for shared element transition this does not happen, it only happens when I use hared element transition.

I use this in the first activity:

```
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, TwoActivity::class.java)
            val p1 = Pair.create<View?, String?>(button1 as View, "btn1")
            val p2 = Pair.create<View?, String?>(button2 as View, "btn2")
            val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this@MainActivity, p1, p2
            ).toBundle()
            startActivity(intent, bundle)
        }
```

and in the activity that receives the animation this is my code to hide the view:

```
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            button4.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

Why is this happening?

Record a video so you can better understand what is happening to me
https://youtu.be/OrKMuLXJBE4